Flutter go_router with go_router_builder how to get current context?
I am using flutters go_router package with the go_router_builder. I want to access the current context from the redirect, but the redirect only provides the app context.
My app's structure looks like this
- splash <- Statelesss Widget
-- home <- Statelesss Widget
--- protected <- Statelesss Widget
-- sign in <- Statelesss Widget

My home page is wrapped with bloc providers. I want to access these BlocProviders when routing to the protected route.
Note: I don't want to pass in the BuildContext as an extra param into the routes as it clutters the app. What I'm looking for is a solution where I provide a navigator key to the entire app which I can then get in the redirect to get the current home page context. But I already tried using the navigator key and it doesn't work.
The code looks like this
@TypedGoRoute<SplashRoute>(
  path: '/',
  name: 'Splash',
)
class SplashRoute extends GoRouteData {
  ...
}

@TypedGoRoute<SignInRoute>(
  path: '/sign-in',
  name: 'Sign In',
)
class SignInRoute extends GoRouteData {
  ...
}

@TypedShellRoute<HomeRoute>(
  routes: <TypedGoRoute<GoRouteData>>[
    TypedGoRoute<ProtectedRoute>(
      path: '/home/protected',
      name: 'Protected',
    ),
  ],
)
class HomeRoute extends ShellRouteData {
  ...
}

class ProtectedRoute extends GoRouteData {
  @override
  FutureOr<String?> redirect(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
    // This context will not have MyCubit as it's wrapped around the HomePage widget
    if(context.read<MyCubit>.state is! MyStateSuccess){
      ...
    }

    return super.redirect(context, state);
  }

  ...
}


Maybe you should place the BlocProvider above the GoRouter in the widget tree. This would allow you to directly access the needed blocs from the context used in the redirect function.

This not what I want as the state should be disposed when the home page pops off the stack. I'm specifically looking for a way to get the context of the current page in the redirect.
